# A mass spring model for hair simulation

Tags: integration, na.numerical-analysis

A strand of hair is represented by a set of particles connected by springs.

The velocity for a particular particle is calculated implicitly using the following formula:
$\boldsymbol{v}^{n+1/2}=\boldsymbol{v}^{n}+\frac{\Delta t}{2}\boldsymbol{a}(t^{n+1/2},\boldsymbol{x}^{n},\boldsymbol{v}^{n+1/2})$

The force or acceleration ($\boldsymbol{a}$ in the above equation) produced by the spring between two adjacent particles is given by the following:
$\boldsymbol{F}^{n+1}=\frac{k}{l_{0}}\left((\boldsymbol{x}_{2}^{n}-\boldsymbol{x}_{1}^{n})^{\mathrm{T}}\hat{\boldsymbol{d}}^{n}-l_{0}\right)\hat{\boldsymbol{d}}^{n}+\Delta t\frac{k}{l_{0}}(\boldsymbol{v}_{2}^{n+1}-\boldsymbol{v}_{1}^{n+1})^{\mathrm{T}}\hat{\boldsymbol{d}}^{n}\hat{\boldsymbol{d}}^{n}$

where $\hat{d}^{n}=(x_{2}^{n}-x_{1}^{n})/\left\Vert x_{2}^{n}-x_{1}^{n}\right\Vert$

My question is, how do you numerically calculate $\boldsymbol{v}_{1}^{n+1}$ and $\boldsymbol{v}_{2}^{n+1}$ in order to calculate the force?

I've tried using Newton's Method but calculating derivative the spring force is just so complicated.

I'm attempting to implement the techniques found in this paper: [link](http://physbam.stanford.edu/~aselle/papers/9/)

Comment: +1 for the cool animations on the linked page.

Comment: I don't know what all the symbols in the formulas stand for but maybe the Newton method is useful http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method

Comment: I'm unsure why this has been deemed off-topic, since it's a legitimate question of research in scientific computing/graphics. Maybe MO is not the right forum for these topics. Anyways. In the paper, the authors suggest an extrapolation step from the $v^{n+1/2}$ stage to $v^{n+1}$, along with a (nebulously defined) post-processing. 

Comment: @Nilima: I share the same feeling about the closure of this question, but I'm unqualified to judge. What you could do is try to start a discussion on meta to hear what others have to say about this particular question.

Comment: @Michael, I did indeed start a discussion on meta about this.


Comment: Meta discussion is here: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1052/

Comment: @Nilima: Thank you for all your input, especially on meta, it made a real difference in getting the question re-opened.

I'm a computer science major and have very little background in numerical analysis. This is also my very first post on MO, so please forgive me for not explaining my problem more clearly.

I've been going through the book by Mark Holmes called "Introduction to Numerical Methods in Differential Equations" in order to familiarise myself with numerical integration techniques. However, I'm still having trouble with applying the techniques covered in the book to Selle's paper.

Comment: Sebastian, you should consider editing the question to make it more widely accessible (I don't have enough points to edit it myself). Specify the ODE, the reduction to first order, clarify the notation (especially the $t_{n+1/2}$ and $t_{n+1}$). Specify the method is explicit in the (nonlinear) force update. You should not need to use a Newton update for the velocity, since the authors claim this can be avoided. They are recommending extrapolation. You can ask the question: what is an accurate and efficient extrapolation strategy for the velocity in this algorithm?

Comment: Nilima, if you email me something ready to go in Latex, I can paste it into the question. One can search with my last name at   http://www.ams.org/cml/  

Note that I know nothing about MathJax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that the only unknown quantities in your force equation are the updated velocities $v_i^{n+1}$, and that force depends linearly on these. Everything else is either known from the last time step, e.g. $x_i^n$, or is a simulation parameter/material constant.

Therefore, after substituting for $\mathbf{a}$ in your first equation, you will end up with a set of *linear* equations in the unknowns $v_i^{n+1/2}$; in particular the system will be of the form
$$(\mathbf{I} - c\Delta t^2\ \mathbf{d}\mathbf{d}^T)\mathbf{v}^{n+1/2} = \mathbf{b}$$
for some scalar $c$ and right-hand side $\mathbf{b}$. You can readily solve this system without Newton's method. In particular, for sufficiently small time steps $\Delta t$ the matrix is positive-definite, in which case I recommend using Conjugate Gradients to solve the system iteratively without ever even needing to form the dense matrix $\mathbf{d}\mathbf{d}^T.$